# Multiple fastcgi program on the same machine

Tags: c++, c, nginx, fastcgi

How can I configure nginx so I can use several fastcgi programs on the same machine. I understood that this example http://www.kutukupret.com/2010/08/20/nginx-fastcgi-hello-world-in-c/ pass all requests to spawned fastcgi process.

I need to make load balancing some heavy computing taks on specialized servers, so I decided to use nginx for this purpose. But maybe there will be several programs and I haven't found tutorial on that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use upstream module and fastcgi module. An example is from nginx official site: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html. You list a list of upstream servers. Nginx will do the rest for you. There are a few options that you can do to fine turn the config below. You may read those module doc for more detail.

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;

    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    ...

    location /fastcgi/ {
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I do so, only one cgi programm will listen on each port. I solved problem using different location for each program.

Comment: I see. Thought all of your upstream programs could perform the same task.